# Cannot see SVG over header

Tags: css, reactjs, svg

Seems pretty simple but trust me to find this difficult, I have a simple header with a background colour and all I want is to put an svg into it.

Here is my component code and the css:

Component

```
import React from "react";
import "./Header.css";

const Header = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <header>
        <div className="socials_row">
          <div>
            <svg
              version="1.1"
              id="Capa_1"
              xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
              x="0px"
              y="0px"
              viewBox="0 0 167.657 167.657"
              className="social_image"
            >
              <g>
                <path
                  fill="white"  d="M83.829,0.349C37.532,0.349,0,37.881,0,84.178c0,41.523,30.222,75.911,69.848,82.57v-65.081H49.626
        v-23.42h20.222V60.978c0-20.037,12.238-30.956,30.115-30.956c8.562,0,15.92,0.638,18.056,0.919v20.944l-12.399,0.006
        c-9.72,0-11.594,4.618-11.594,11.397v14.947h23.193l-3.025,23.42H94.026v65.653c41.476-5.048,73.631-40.312,73.631-83.154
        C167.657,37.881,130.125,0.349,83.829,0.349z"
                />
              </g>
              <g></g>
              <g></g>
              <g></g>
              <g></g>
              <g></g>
              <g></g>
              <g></g>
              <g></g>
              <g></g>
              <g></g>
              <g></g>
              <g></g>
              <g></g>
              <g></g>
              <g></g>
            </svg>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="main_header"></div>
      </header>
    </>
  );
};

export default Header;
```

CSS

```
.socials_row {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: end;
    background-color: green;
    padding: 5px 30px;
}

.social_image {
    max-height: 25px;
    max-width: 25px;
    fill: white;
}
```

Ive also tried inline styling but cant get it to appear, when I try to inspect the element it highlights it as if its under the header

Comment: Delete the fill:white attribute of the path. Also: why do you have so many empty groups?

Comment: I deleted the empty groups and the fill attribute, I still can't see anything. The empty groups came from the website I got the SVG from, I did not add them

Comment: there is also a fill:white in the css for the .social_image

Comment: @enxaneta I got rid of that, still not showing

Comment: please come with a working snippet, if you have a snippet that shows your problem clearly, it will solve your problem much faster compare to come without a snippet, in example, you can create a snippet from code sandbox